# HTML breaking when downloading as PDF document but working for view report

Tags: html, css, sql, asp.net, html-table

Below HTML code logic is written in sql and being called from ASP.net page where option is provided for view report and and download as PDF. View report is working fine however downloaded report is working abnormally
Below first output is from view report which is right. I am excepting he same output in pdf as from view report.

```
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">049</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40</td><td style="width: 20%;">36.00000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">060412</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
<hr />
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">273</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40</td><td style="width: 20%;">42.40000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">00413</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
<hr />
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">598</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">48</td><td style="width: 20%;">28.80000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">000911</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
<hr />
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">251856</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40</td><td style="width: 20%;">54.00000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">0000910</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
<hr />
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">239</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40</td><td style="width: 20%;">63.60000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">0000908</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>'
```

Expected output

Item Number Quantity Ordered Price 049 4036.00000CA UPC Case Code: 060412 Vendor Item:

---

Item Number Quantity Ordered Price 273 4042.40000CA UPC Case Code: 00413 Vendor Item:

---

Item Number Quantity Ordered Price 598 4828.80000CA UPC Case Code: 000911 Vendor Item:

---

Item Number Quantity Ordered Price 251856 4054.00000CA UPC Case Code: 0000910 Vendor Item:

---

Item Number Quantity Ordered Price 239 4063.60000CA UPC Case Code: 0000908 Vendor Item:

```
wrong output from PDF as below:(only one row of sample is given here)
```

Item Number | Quantity Ordered | Price&nbsp | 049 |40 |36.00000&nbsp
|CA UPC Case Code: 060412 Vendor Item:

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed about your HTML, your last line has 3 unpaired tags `</td></tr></table>`, so remove those.

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but it is a method to get to PDF and it is outputting how you expected.

I created a print button, that prints the window when clicked. Wrapped your tables in `<div id="printable-page"></div>` which contains the content you want to print, then you can click the button to open up a print preview window, and print the window/file to PDF like so:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlGZQ.png

```js
$('a.printPage').click(function(){
          $('#printable-page').show();
             window.print();
             return false;
  });
```

```css
page { size:  auto; margin: 25mm 25mm 25mm 25mm; } 
@media print {
  #search,
  .printPage {
    display: none !important;
  }
 }
 .printbtn{
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0px; 
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.printPage {
  background-color: #104723;
  color: #b3ab7d;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="printbtn">
    <a class="printPage" href="#">Print Page</a>
</div>


<div id="printable-page">
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">049</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40</td><td style="width: 20%;">36.00000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">060412</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
<hr />
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">273</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40</td><td style="width: 20%;">42.40000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">00413</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
<hr />
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">598</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">48</td><td style="width: 20%;">28.80000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">000911</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
<hr />
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">251856</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40</td><td style="width: 20%;">54.00000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">0000910</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
<hr />
<table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 2px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Item Number</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Quantity Ordered</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;"><span style="font-style: italic;">Price</span>&nbsp</td><td style="width: 20%;"></td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr></table><table class="Grid_Text" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; border: 0;"><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"><span style="font-weight: bold;">239</span>&nbsp;</td><td style="width: 20%;">40</td><td style="width: 20%;">63.60000</td><td style="width: 20%;">CA</td><td style="width: 25%;"></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> UPC Case Code: </td><td class="NoWrap">0000908</td></tr><tr><td class="NoWrap" style="width: 25%;"> Vendor Item: </td><td class="NoWrap"></td></tr></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After I added semicolon in all the static values that solves the issues and it worked in both cases